# SQL Creating a table with vertical default

Tags: mysql

I have a code that I started, but according to my error I'm messing up at the part where I have to define the default to vertical. I tried looking for this in my book and it didn't mention vertical defaults or even adding values for defaults.. Example, where it says the default is 15 for the the email_frequency. I feel like this is a simple syntax error but, I can't find anywhere in my book that explains how to define the default column.

I'll attach the expected output and then the code I have made up so far with the error.

Expected answer:

```
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+-------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default  | Extra |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+-------+
| user_id         | int(7)              | NO   |     | NULL     |       |
| email_frequency | tinyint(2) unsigned | YES  |     | 15       |       |
| layout          | varchar(70)         | YES  |     | vertical |       |
| updated_at      | datetime            | YES  |     | NULL     |       |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------+-------+
```

Code I have so far:

```
   CREATE TABLE settings (
user_id INT(7) NOT NULL,
email_frequency TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 15 NULL,
layout VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT VERTICAL NULL,
updated_at YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS NULL
);
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
 corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VER
TICAL NULL,
updated_at YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS NULL
)' at line 4
```

Comment: You're missing commas.

Comment: Oh my gosh. I feel dumb.

Comment: Okay, I updated it with the commas, and the error that I was originally getting which is near the vertical statement.

Comment: Now you're missing quotes. `'VERTICAL'`. Either that, or change the type of `layout` to an `ENUM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. "Vertical" should be a string literal, so it needs to be denoted by single quotes (`'`)
2. You're missing commas (`,`) between the column definitions
3. `updated_at`'s datatype should be `datetime`

So:

```
CREATE TABLE settings (
    user_id INT(7) NOT NULL,
    email_frequency TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 15 NULL,
    layout VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT 'VERTICAL' NULL,
    updated_at DATETIME NULL
);
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. and thank you for explaining. This was extremely helpful.